# Build tree-hierachy from two-dimensional list

Tags: python, list, tree

I have a 2D-list that looks something like this:

```
[
    ["elem1","elem2"],
    ["elem1","elem3"],
    ["elem4","elem7"],
...
]
```

And I want to create a nested dictionary that then looks something like this:

```
[{"elem1":["elem2","elem3"]},{"elem4":"elem7"}]
```

So the higher the index in one of the initial sublists the higher will be the hierachical posiiton in the generated tree. How would you go about this in python? How do you call that "treeification"? I feel like there has to be a package out there that does exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't imagine there is something in a library for this considering it is fairly simple and not that useful for most people. It is better to write the code manually.

First of all, the output format in the question cannot fully represent a tree: for example the data

```
[
    ["elem1", "elem2"],
    ["elem1", "elem3"],
    ["elem4", "elem7"],
    ["elem3", "elem5"],
]
```

...would need to be similar to `[{elem1":["elem2","elem3"]},{"elem4":"elem7"}]` but add `elem5` as a child of `elem3`, however `elem3` is a string type, with no place for children to be stored. Thus, I suggest the following output format:

`{'elem4': {'elem7': {}}, 'elem1': {'elem2': {}, 'elem3': {'elem5': {}}}}`

Here every node is represented as a dictionary from child node names to child node values, so a tree containing only a root node looks like `{}`, and a tree with 3 nodes (the root + 2 children) looks like `{'child1': {}, 'child2': {}}`.

To take the turn a list of parent-child associations and turn them into such a tree you can use this code:

```
def treeify(data):
    # result dictionary
    map_list = {}
    # initially all nodes with a child, will have items removed later
    root_nodes = {parent for parent, child in data}

    for parent, child in data:
        # get the dictionary that this node maps to (empty dictionary by default)
        children = map_list.setdefault(parent, {})
        # add this connection
        children[child] = map_list.setdefault(child, {})
        # remove node with a parent from the set of root_nodes
        if child in root_nodes:
            root_nodes.remove(child)

    # return the dictionary with only root nodes at the root
    return dict((root_node, map_list[root_node]) for root_node in root_nodes)

print(treeify([
    ["elem1", "elem2"],
    ["elem1", "elem3"],
    ["elem4", "elem7"],
    ["elem3", "elem5"],
]))
```

Comment: This looks exacly like what I was looking for. Thank you for your efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is code which can help you to get as your required output

```
data = [
    ["elem1","elem2"],
    ["elem1","elem3"],
    ["elem4","elem7"],
]

maplist = {}
for a in data:
    if a[0] in maplist:
         maplist[a[0]].append(a[1])
    else:
        maplist[a[0]] = [a[1]]

print(maplist)
```

To get sorted based on list item you can use below code

```
sorted_items = sorted(maplist.items(), key = lambda item : len(item[1]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: That looks great, thank you. But is there a more general way to do this? What if the depth/length of the list is longer than two or varies in length?